# GCP Cloud Storage REST API endpoint is always "https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I had a question while testing the REST APIs of AWS S3 and GCP Cloud Storage.

AWS S3 REST api endpoint is equal to s3 bucket endpoint

```
ex) https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>
```

But GCP Cloud Storage REST api endpoint is different from GCP Cloud bucket endpoint

```
ex) bucket endpoint
https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket_name>

ex) REST api endpoint
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>
```

I am confused due to the above differences, but if I were to ask, is the CCP Cloud Storage REST API endpoint always fixed? Is there absolutely no possibility of it changing?

if it does change, please explain under what circumstances it changes.

Comment: There are multiple endpoints (more than you mention). Which one to use depends on a number of factors. Consult this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints) for details. It is unlikely that the endpoints would change, but even if they did, a simple HTTP Status 307 would make that transparent. AWS has been using S3 storage redirects for many years to change endpoints. The key to remember is that AWS S3 has fewer authorization mechanisms compared to Google Cloud Storage. For the noob that can be confusing. Once you master authorization, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>/` is the default URL choice for GCS. It uses what's documented as the GCS XML API. It works with web browsers and client libraries.

`https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket_name>` is a special purpose domain pattern. It allows you to use your browser's google.com cookies as a credential, so if you're logged in to your Google account and your account has access to that bucket, you can access your stuff at that URL. For security reasons, access to this endpoint has several additional restrictions that are not necessary on other endpoints. It's useful if you need to view your own objects with a web browser, but for most GCS use cases (like when you're writing a program to access resources or serving data to anonymous users), it's probably not the URL you want.

Comment: You are the authority on this topic. Can you add details to clarify what an endpoint is for Cloud Storage? I count more than two based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints) but that depends on how an endpoint is defined.

Comment: You're right, the term doesn't seem to have a consistent definition in this documentation. I think it's being used for "a specific URL pattern," but that's pretty vague. Thanks for the feedback, I'll pass it along.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the pattern is

a) Public URL - Anyone with this link can access the object on the public internet

`https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>/<file_name>`

b) Authenticated URL - Only users granted permission can access the object with this link
`https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket_name>/<file_name>`

You can verify the above by uploading any file to your bucket. Then go to cloud storage and click on the file. YOu should get links like the above. For the public url, you first have to make the file available to every one

Answer (score 2):

The Google Cloud Storage REST API endpoint is fixed as `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>.`

Google uses the `https://storage.googleapis.com/` domain for programmatic access (e.g., API calls), while the `https://storage.cloud.google.com/` domain is used for the Google Cloud Console UI, which is more user-friendly and provides visualisations, navigation, and controls for interacting with the data.

It's highly unlikely that these endpoints would change because they are part of Google Cloud's public API, and changing them would break compatibility for all existing applications using the API. Like other major cloud providers, Google maintains stability in their APIs to ensure developers can rely on them over time.

That being said, the specifics of how to construct URLs, including the bucket names and paths, could change in new API versions. However, Google would almost certainly provide advance notice of such changes and offer migration paths.